# Javascript, and radio buttons

Tags: radio-button

OK here is the deal.  I have a survey that I am putting up with over 60 questions.  I want to make them all mandatory.  I really need to know if the group has a value, don't care what it is.

Here is what I have, but it is only giving me the first value.

```
<function CheckField(myFieldName, myText){
var x=document.getElementById(myFieldName).value;
window.alert(myFieldName + "1: " +x);
```

. . .. . .

OK so this returns the first value of 5.  It does not matter what I select.  All I just need to know if they selected something if not I want to mark the question with a different color so the user knows to go back and answer the question.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your html too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radio button required - JavaScript validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116149/radio-button-required-javascript-validation)

Comment: You need to check the 'checked' property of the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: (EASY!)**

Having the attribute "checked" set to "true" would make have a default value either way.

```
<input type="radio" name="option" />Option 1
<input type="radio" name="option" checked="true" />Option 2
```

You could also use `required` instead of `checked` attribute but some browsers don't support it like Safari.

**For info on support:**

[required](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

[checked](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

**Option 2:
JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/FE7sK/2/

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#validateOpt').bind('click', checkRadio);
})

function checkRadio() {
    var isChecked = jQuery("input[type=radio]:checked").val();

    var booleanVlaueIsChecked = false;
    if (isChecked) {
        booleanVlaueIsChecked = true;
        $('#form1').submit();
    } else {
        alert("aaa");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try HTML5 `required`:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="option" required /> Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="option" /> Option 2</label>
```

You can use it on one radio (per each name), or on all of them (see [HTML5: How to use the "required" attribute with a "radio" input field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8287779/1529630)).